# Include file with his dependencies in PHP

Tags: php

My root project folder is:

```
c:\phpproject\data_valid.php
```

In this folder I have a library I need to use:

```
c:\phpproject\vendor\egulias\email-validator\src\EmailValidator.php
```

Inside data_valid.php I include the library I need:

```
//data_valid.php

include ('vendor\egulias\email-validator\src\EmailValidator.php');
```

The EmailValidator.php has dependencies:

```
//EmailValidator.php


namespace Egulias\EmailValidator;

use Egulias\EmailValidator\Result\InvalidEmail;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\EmailValidation;
```

When I run the data_valid.php script I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailLexer"
```

So, the data_valid.php file doesn't know where the EmailLexer.php is, being this file called from EmailValidation.php. If I include EmailLexer.php in data_valid.php it is found

```
 //data_valid.php
include ('vendor\egulias\email-validator\src\EmailValidator.php');
include ('vendor\egulias\email-validator\src\EmailLexer.php');
```

But more dependendencies are missing:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Doctrine\Common\Lexer\AbstractLexer
```

It seems that PHP doesn't include the dependencies of a library automatically.

How do I do that?

PD. After some research I found that including:

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

It loads everything.

But I am still curious how to do it without using  include 'vendor/autoload.php'. For example, I have a bunch of classes inside multiple files in a directory. In this scenario I need to call one class but that class depends in multiple classes defined in multiple files in that directory.

Comment: Stick with composers `include 'vendor/autoload.php';` as this will pick up that you are instantiating a class that it does not know about and go search for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use composer: https://getcomposer.org/

It also allows for manual inclusion of custom classes etc.

I don't recommend manually including all the necessary classes as you would need some recursive search for this anyway.

Comment: PHP doesn't support something like "import" in Python? In python you import a file and that file imports other files and so on.

Comment: It does via require / include, see: https://www.php.net/require
But it does not automatically include other files, only if those also have recursive requires.
Composer is a de facto standard for using different libraries.

Comment: I mean, in the EmailValidator.php file there is no "include" or "require". It seems that that file assumes that the requires dependencies are under the same folder.

Comment: I think I found the concept: is called Autoloading. From Internet source: "Autoloading allows us to use PHP classes without the need to require or include them
and is considered a hallmark of modern-day programming".